# How to compare the values in a list of dictionaries with input values

Tags: python

I am now trying to make a program that is using for matching a suitable immigration country. And I find out some problems while running it.

Here are some demo-data required for the system:

```
data = [{'Country': 'Taiwan','Age': 18, 'Status': 'False', 'Education level': 1}, 
        {'Country': 'Japan','Age': 30, 'Status': 'True', 'Education level': 8},
        {'Country': 'Korea','Age': 20, 'Status': 'False', 'Education level': 6}]
ans = ["yes", "no", "Y", "N", "y", "n", "Yes", "No"]
ans_y = ["yes", "Y", "y", "Yes"]
ans_n = ["no", "N", "n", "No"]
```

Then I start to ask for the user's information with some `Error Handling`.

```
def collecting_info():
    age = 0
    while True:
        try:
            age = int(input('\nWhat is your age?'))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please insert valid input.")
            continue

    while True:
        status = str(input('Are you married?'))
        if status not in ans:
            print("Please insert the valid input.)")
            continue
        else:
            break

    print("\nYou are {} year-old".format(age))

    # print status
    if status in ans:
        if status in ans_y:
            status = 'True'
            print("You are Married.")

        elif status in ans_n:
            status = 'False'
            print("You are not Married.")
        return status, age
    age_match()
```

After that, I start to do the matching, my idea is using `for...loop` to delete the unmatched `dictionary` and print the most suitable place at the end.

```
# matching age
def age_match():
    age = collecting_info()
    for dict_age in data:
        for age_dict in dict_age:
            ad = iter(age_dict)
            if ad == 'Age':
                if age_dict.value > age:
                    del data[dict_age]


# matching marriage
def status_match():
    status = collecting_info()
    for dict_status in data:
        for status_dict in dict_status:
            sd = iter(status_dict)
            if sd == str('Status\n(tick = M)'):
                if status_dict.value == status:
                    del data[dict_status]
print(data)
```

However, the program only returns the value of Age and Status......(my input--- Age: 20; Status: no)

> ```
> You are 20 year-old
> You are not Married.
> ```

My expected output is

```
[{'Country': 'Korea','Age': 20, 'Status': 'False', 'Education level': 6}]
```

This is my first time to make a program by myself, I hope I could get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think is a good idea to modify list when looping it

```
data = [{'Country': 'Taiwan','Age': 18, 'Status': 'False', 'Education level': 1},
        {'Country': 'Japan','Age': 30, 'Status': 'True', 'Education level': 8},
        {'Country': 'Korea','Age': 20, 'Status': 'False', 'Education level': 6}]
ans = ["yes", "no", "Y", "N", "y", "n", "Yes", "No"]
ans_y = ["yes", "Y", "y", "Yes"]
ans_n = ["no", "N", "n", "No"]

def collecting_info():
    age = 0
    while True:
        try:
            age = int(input('\nWhat is your age?'))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please insert valid input.")
            continue

    while True:
        status = str(input('Are you married?'))
        if status not in ans:
            print("Please insert the valid input.)")
            continue
        else:
            break

    print("\nYou are {} year-old".format(age))

    # print status
    if status in ans:
        if status in ans_y:
            status = 'True'
            print("You are Married.")

        elif status in ans_n:
            status = 'False'
            print("You are not Married.")
    return age, status

# matching age
def age_match(age):
    data_copy = []
    for people in data:
        if people['Age'] == age:
            data_copy.append(people)
    return data_copy


# matching marriage
def status_match(status):
    data_copy = []
    for people in data:
        if people['Status'] == status:
            data_copy.append(people)
    return  data_copy

age, status = collecting_info()
age_group = age_match(age)
status_group = status_match(status)
for p in age_group:
    if p in status_group:
        print(p)
```

Comment: Maybe you have some recommended solutions, I hope I could improve my work.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
age, status = collecting_info()
result = [d for d in data if d['Age'] == age and d['Status'] == status]
```

instead of `age_match` and `status_match`